# Adding multiple users to yammer group via PowerShell or Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, yammer, yammer-api

Looking for a way through which I can add multiple users to a yammer group.

[I tried this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-add-user-to-yammer-group-using-powershell), but it doesn't work.

Is there any PowerShell scripts or an option available on the UI to add multiple users? I also tried to separate the users via comma delimiters but this doesn't work either.

Have also tried adding a AAD group but that didn't work either (the group doesn't appears in the dropdown).

Below is the PS script:

```
# Input Parameters    
$developerToken = "999-test"   
$uri="https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/group_memberships.json"  
$headers = @{ Authorization=("Bearer " + $developerToken) }     
$body=@{group_id="groupid";email="test@test.com"}   
  
# Invoke Web Request - Add user to Group  
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $uri –Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Comment: What happened when you tried using the code in the linked article? What response did you get from the yammer server? Were you seeing any error messages? Please be mindful that only you can see your screen :)

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Missed to add the message :) )

Comment: Do you have a copy of your code that you're running?

Comment: Added the code in the question